Minecraft LAN server works only through direct-connect
I know this problem was mentioned in one thread, but it was 6 years and no answer.
On Windows 10, I can connect to my bro's LAN world only through direct connect by specifying his local IP address and port. I remember that in the past it used to show up automatically in the multiplayer tab (now since some time it doesn't). I read that it does have something to do with port 4445, which the LAN server uses to announce itself as open. My brother's PC listens for the 4445 port when in the multiplayer tab.
What can be the reason for that my PC is not sending anything on the 4445 port? I tried fiddling with netcat by sending a payload or any other message over to 224.0.2.60:4445, but nothing happened (on another PC I set up listening, but I couldn't see anything while sending on the 224.0.2.60 IP; it only worked when I sent on 192.168.XX.XX).
Can this have something to do with me being behind CGNAT? (Earlier I tried setting up a dedicated server and found out I couldn't because my ISP has put me behind CGNAT.) At first I thought that CGNAT should only interfere when trying to port-forward, and it doesn't have to do anything with setting up LAN.

Are you trying to ask "How do I broadcast/advertise a server over LAN?"?

Also, your question is kinda complicated and doesn't make any sense. Do you think you could rewrite it so that it is easier to read?

Also, this might be of interest: https://bitbucket.org/minerz029/lan_broadcaster/src/735deb37f01362075b55d0b1c006fe627053db4f/lan_broadcaster.py#lines-107

I checked both PCs with wireshark and it turned out my brother's PC communicated with port 4445 using VirtualBox's network card (Peculiarly the only communication that was on this card was the 4445 port). I turned off the card in device manager which moved port 4445 to his main network card and now everything works as it should - the LAN world shows up automatically.

VirtualBox? You mean you're running under a VM? You should have mentioned that in your question.

Frankly, I had no idea that my brother has ever had VirtualBox installed, while testing our LAN server the VM wasn't even running (VirtualBox was closed) - so that's why we didn't know where to look.
